# I want to make timer to stop and put on the other scene. So, it will be a score, but how?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, if the player hit the finish line the game will be done and go to "FinishScene". In "FinishScene" i want the timer result to appear on the finish scene, so the player know how much time did the player use to make 'til the end.

I already watch so many youtube videos but it doesn't help me. Hope someone could help me!

Timer Script:

```
public Text timerText;
private float startTime;

void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

void Update()
{
    float t = Time.time - startTime;

    string minutes = ((int) t / 60).ToString();
    string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

    timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Finish Scene:
[image: Finish Scene Photo]

Trying to pass timer result.

Comment: Please do not use the `[visual-studio]` tag for questions unless they are about using the Visual Studio application. You can read the tag's description for more information.

Comment: Can you advise what the problem is with the code you have presently?

Comment: There's no problem with the code, i just want to add my timer result to the "FinishScene".

Comment: Btw, the timer is count up.

Comment: Well, thank you for your illuminating comments.

Comment: @shingo i hope so, but where should i put the script?